# Dynamic row layout for ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, textview

I have a ListView where I send data from a database using `SimpleCursorAdapter`, but I need to have dynamic row layout, because every table can have different number of columns.

Let's say I create `TextViews` according to the number of columns:

```
    public int getColumnNumbers() {
        int i = 0;

        cursor = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info("+DATABASE_TABLE_NAME+")", null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                i++;
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();

        return i;
    }

  ........

    int rowsNumber = getColumnNumbers();
    textViews = new TextView[rowsNumber];

    for(i = 0; i < rowsNumber; i++) {
        textViews[i] = new TextView(this);
        textViews[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
```

What I'm basically looking for, is a way to get these `TextViews` passed to `CursorAdapter`'s (or other adapter's) argument `int[] to`

I'm pretty new to this, so I would appreciate any help or advice.

**EDIT:**

I'm adding my implementation of `bindView`method,  which I made with help of the links provided here, in case someone would have to face similar issue in the future.

```
    @Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    int i, count = myHelper.getColumnNumbers();
    String[] columnNames = myHelper.getColumnNamesString();
    String text;
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_horizontal);

    for(i = 0; i < (count-1); i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(columnNames[i+1]));
        textView.setText(text);

        layout.addView((TextView)textView);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I found out yesterday that the implementation mentioned above works until you need to scroll. After scrolling, ListView gets deformed.
So again, in case someone would like to do something similar, I'm adding my whole Adapter class.

```
public class DatabaseCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
private DatabaseHelper myHelper;
private int count;
private String[] columnNames;

public DatabaseCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
    myHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    count = myHelper.getColumnNumbers();
    columnNames = myHelper.getColumnNamesString();
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.text_select, parent, false);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_horizontal);
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
        textView.setTag(Integer.valueOf(i));
        layout.addView(textView);
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    int i;
    String text;

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewWithTag(Integer.valueOf(i));
        text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(columnNames[i]));
        textView.setText(text);
    }
}
}
```

In the and, as it is with most issues, the solution is pretty easy. Technique is almost the same as if you would use a static layout, except instead of using `findViewById`, you just tag elements of your layout and use `findViewWithTag` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at good tutorial, a link is 
[Populating a ListView with a CursorAdapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter) . The web page has some nice explanations.

Look at `TodoCursorAdapter` and the `bindView` method to check which column/data is available from the database. Snippet of code from tutorial:

```
@Override
  public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
      // Find fields to populate in inflated template
      TextView tvBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvBody);
      // Extract properties from cursor
      String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
      // Populate fields with extracted properties
      tvBody.setText(body);
  }
```

I think this is a simple code design.
Code in the webpage to populate data onto Listview:

```
// Find ListView to populate
ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
// Setup cursor adapter using cursor from last step
TodoCursorAdapter todoAdapter = new TodoCursorAdapter(this, todoCursor);
// Attach cursor adapter to the ListView 
lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
```

You can implement an **ArrayAdapter** instead of CursorAdapter. This makes sense if your app is not continually interfacing with the database. The link is [Using an ArrayAdapter with ListView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) . It is the same website.
In this case, look at `getView` method instead of the similar bindView.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know which way I should head exactly, I will definitely look at this.

Comment: I edited my answer to include another good link using an ArrayAdapter instead of CursorAdapter that you mentioned.

Comment: Looking at the links you provided, both examples show only scenario where I know in advance how many TextViews I will need in a row, therefore they can be specified in the xml layout. In my case, I don't know how many TextViews will be needed, it differs from table to table, so I'm looking for a way how to dynamically create TextViews and attach them to the adapter.

Comment: Before we get further on creating TextViews dynamically, let me say this. The LinearLayout is for only 1 (virtual) ListView which supports many several TextViews, depending on the number of row data (parameter position) you will get from the database. This is memory efficient.

Comment: Yes, but how can I map number of row data (columns) to number of `TextViews`? Adapter needs integer value of target `TextViews`, usually specified by `R.id`, but at this case, I can't get this value. I tried using `setId(int id)` and `getId()` methods, but apparently, this isn't the right way.

Comment: I add the sample code in my answer in object todoAdapter. Basically I am saying you have only 1 ListView and the row data is loaded onto a ListView dynamically using virtual memory. Will that work for your app?

Comment: Another, an ArrayAdapter has the override getCount() which can be called by the object, never used it though. Perhaps you can use it to check how many TextViews to create, still I don't like that idea though.

Comment: It works, thank you! It took me a while to realise how to use bindView, but your links and code samples helped a lot. I will add my implementation of Adapter to my question, in case someone would have similar issue in the future.

Comment: I am glad for you, time to party now. It's the weekend. One problem down, hundreds more to solve, haha.